# Creating a grid of coloured points

Tags: color

I wish to create a grid of 31x31 points with coordinates of the form $(k/30,n/30)$ within the unit square, and give each point a colour based on the 2-adic value of both its coördinates.

I plan to use Wolfram Mathematica, as this program has a simple function to calculate the 2-adic value, but I do not know how to generate a grid in which I can assign colours to the points. If we write $v(x)$ as the 2-adic value of $x$, the colouring should be as follows:

$(x,y)$ is coloured:

- Blue if $v(x) \geq v(y)$ and $v(x) \geq v(1)=1$
- Green if $v(x) < v(y)$ and $v(y) \geq v(1)=1$
- Red if $v(x) < v(1)=1 $ and $ v(y) < v(1)=1$

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please add any code you have tried.

Comment: Take a look at [`ArrayPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayPlot.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know much about 2-adic values, hence I took the code for it from this [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html) article.
Here are a couple of solutions to do it:

### Using Graphics

```
PadicNorm[x_Integer, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := p^(-IntegerExponent[x, p])
PadicNorm[x_Rational, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
 PadicNorm[Numerator[x], p]/PadicNorm[Denominator[x], p]
v[x_] := PadicNorm[x, 2]
Graphics[{
  Table[{PointSize@0.016,
    Which[
     v[k/30] >= v[n/30] && v[k/30] >= 1, Blue,
     v[k/30] < v[n/30] && v[n/30] >= 1, Green,
     v[k/30] < 1 && v[n/30] < 1, Red
     ],
    Point[{k/30, n/30}]
    },
   {k, 0, 30}, {n, 0, 30}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

Which produces the following:
[image]

### Using squares instead of points

Using appropriate substitutions on a ConstantArray and selectively changing the background color:

```
PadicNorm[x_Integer, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := p^(-IntegerExponent[x, p])
PadicNorm[x_Rational, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
 PadicNorm[Numerator[x], p]/PadicNorm[Denominator[x], p]
vx[j_] := PadicNorm[(j - 1)/30, 2]
vy[i_] := PadicNorm[(31 - i)/30, 2]
ReplacePart[
  ConstantArray[0, {31, 31}],
  {{i_, j_} :> 
    Item[" ", Background -> Blue] /; vx[j] >= vy[i] && vx[j] >= 1,
   {i_, j_} :> 
    Item[" ", Background -> Green] /; vx[j] < vy[i] && vy[i] >= 1,
   {i_, j_} :> Item[" ", Background -> Red] /; vx[j] < 1 && vy[i] < 1}
  ] // Grid
```

The functions `vx` and `vy` serve to easily convert between the numbering of the elements of a matrix and the required cartesian way of ordering coordinates. Here is the output:
[image]

### Output squares using Graphics

Slight modification of the previously used code with `Graphics`:

```
PadicNorm[x_Integer, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := p^(-IntegerExponent[x, p])
PadicNorm[x_Rational, p_Integer?PrimeQ] := 
 PadicNorm[Numerator[x], p]/PadicNorm[Denominator[x], p]
v[x_] := PadicNorm[x, 2]
Graphics[{
  Table[
   {
    Which[
     v[k/30] >= v[n/30] && v[k/30] >= 1, Blue,
     v[k/30] < v[n/30] && v[n/30] >= 1, Green,
     v[k/30] < 1 && v[n/30] < 1, Red
     ],
    Rectangle[{k/30, n/30}, {(k + 1)/30, (n + 1)/30}]
    },
   {k, 0, 30}, {n, 0, 30}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I needed! Yet, is there a way to, instead of colouring adjacent squares, colour loose points in the unit square?

Comment: @Pepijn of course. Sorry I didn't understand that that's what you needed. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed!